# Database connection C#

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I have a question according to this code. VisualStudio shows no errors or warnings but when I run it, the result is only the exceptionerror ("Something went wrong."). This is how I have always done it before but somehow always worked except for now. Am I missing a simple thing?

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Connect
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\royva\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CookieMultiView\CookieMultiView\App_Data\Databank.mdb';Persist Security Info=True";
        // Execute
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM teachers = ?";// + Request.QueryString["id"];
        lbl.Text = "";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id",Request.QueryString["id"]);


        // Read
        try
        {
           conn.Open();
           OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               lbl.Text = reader["teacherid"].ToString();
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //lbl.Text = ex.StackTrace;                
            lbl.Text = "Something went wrong.";
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Remove `lbl.Text = "Something went wrong.";` and then put a break point on `lbl.Text = ex.StackTrace;`  and step through it. Also you're adding a param `id` but it's not in your select query

Comment: Check your commandText i think it should be something like that:
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id = ?"

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `lbl.Text = "Something went wrong.";` line and see what is the actual exception. As of now, it can be any of the hundred issues.

Comment: I've changed the commandtext and its sadly still not fixed.

Also i've used the breakpoint and got 3 exceptions, access to patch 'c/blabla/temporary ASP.NET Files' is denied.

"Invalid file name for file monitoring"

"no value given for one or more required parameters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Detailed info of the `Exception`,

```
catch (Exception ex)
 {
   //Either you can write log or display in label
   lbl.Text = ex.Message;
 }
```

Also check the folder access rights for

```
Data Source='C:\Users\royva\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CookieMultiView\CookieMultiView\App_Data\Databank.mdb'
```

Programmatically to check for specific files use `File.Exists(path)`, which will return a `boolean` indicating whether the file at path exists.

And validate if the connection has been established or not.

Comment: It's a local database and the database is put there via visual studio's.

The error i get with your tip of ex.message is "No value given for one or more required parameters." This will help me out! Thanks :)

Comment: It was indeed the connection, somehow the database was on read-only. Got it working now! Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear @RoyvanderPlas :)